# Ruby on Rails: How do I sum up these elements in my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a video_votes table with all the votes with a column called value set to 1 or -1. I want to sum up all the values of the video's votes and display that net vote count. First, how should I sum this up, and second, should I store this value in my video table? If so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start with this until performance became an issue:

```
class Video < AR::Base
  has_many :video_votes

  def vote_sum
    video_votes.sum(:value)
  end
end

class VideoVote < AR::Base
  belongs_to :video
  validates_inclusion_of :value, :in => [-1,1]
end
```

Once performance became an issue and I wanted to cache the summed value I might do something like this:

```
class Video < AR::Base
  has_many :video_votes

  # Override vote_sum attribute to get the db count if not stored in the db yet. 
  # The alternative is that you could remove this method and have the field
  # populated by a migration.
  def vote_sum
    read_attribute(:vote_sum) || video_votes.sum(:value)
  end
end

class VideoVote < AR::Base
  belongs_to :video
  validates_inclusion_of :value, :in => [-1,1]

  after_create :update_video_vote_sum

private

  def update_video_vote_sum
    video.update_attributes(:vote_sum => video.vote_sum + value)
  end
end
```

Check out the AR documentation on "Overwriting default accessors" (scroll down a bit)
http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: I like this. What does read_attribute() do? I don't get the vote_sum method. Also, does it need to be `@video.video_votes.sum('value')`?

Comment: read_attribute(:vote_sum) would read the vote_sum field in the video table. If it was nil it would then call the sum method on the relationship. In a view you would just do @video.vote_sum to get the sum. In the video vote class you then just update the sum in on the video object when a new vote is saved.

Comment: You are in essence adding behavior to the vote_sum method defined by active record. You could also write a migration to populate the vote_sum field and remove that method. You could also start by not caching the vote sum until it becomes a performance issue. Will Update the answer with that strategy.

Comment: by the way, does `video_votes.sum(:value)` in the `vote_sum` method make sure that it's only the rows that are associated with that particular video?

Comment: Yes. @video.vote_sum is the same as calling @video.video_votes.sum(:value) in example #1. The benefit is your views will be cleaner and you can write unit tests for the logic in the model. It will also allow you to move the value into the database field if performance becomes an issue without needed to update your views.

Comment: Oh, so you think I shouldn't initially store the sum in the db? Any reason why I shouldn't go right ahead with the 2nd caching example?

Comment: Technically I should not go right ahead with caching, because it adds extra complexity. If votes can change, votes can be removed, it gets a tad more complex to keep the cached value in sync. But if that is not the case, and you know you will have a lot of votes, and a lot of views, then it might be worthwhile. But watch out for premature optimisation: doing effort that is actually never needed. Just keep it in mind for when it's actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

In your Video model:

```
def total_votes
  self.votes.sum(:value)
end
```

So an example might be:

```
@video.total_votes
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume I should call @video.total_votes as a callback in my video_votes model? Will it be able to reach the method in the Video model?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ActiveRecord's `sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) method.

```
VideoVote.sum('value')
```

You shouldn't store it in the same table. If you have other fields you want to summarize then create a "summary" table and periodically summarize the fields and store the values there. ActiveRecord's other [calculation methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html) might be of interest in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm to sum 2 fields on the level a model:

```
  def update_sum_times
    update_attribute(:sum_of_fields, calc_two_dates)
  end

  def calc_two_dates
    date_one + date_two
  end
```